# Code to check if file exists in JQuery is not working

Tags: jquery

My JQuery code:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 var response = jQuery.ajax({

  url: 'filename.jpg',
  type: 'HEAD',
  async: true,

  error: function()
  {
   return "file does not exist";
  },
  success: function()
  {
   return "file exists";
  }

 });

 alert (response);

});

</script>
```

does not return anything. It should return either "file does not exist" or "file exists" and the message should be shown in an alert box. But the alert box has `[object Object]` value instead.

Comment: Try with `alert (JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: It gives {"readyState":1}, how to get the "file exists" message?

Comment: As it says in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `jQuery.ajax()` return a jqXHR object. `jQuery.ajax()` is also asynchronous so the value you get immediately after calling it won't yet be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. When you call `alert (response);` response has not been resolved yet. I suggest something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'filename.jpg',
         type: 'HEAD',
         async: true,

         error: function()
         {
             handleResponse("file does not exist");
         },
         success: function()
         {
             handleResponse("file exists");
         }
     });

 });

 function handleResponse(response){
      alert(response);
 }
```

or just move the alert into the error/success functions.

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
loadAnImage = new Image();
loadAnImage.onload = function() {/*success*/}
loadAnImage.onerror = function() {/*error*/}
loadAnImage.src = "/*URL HERE*/";
```

Comment: ok, I am trying. please be online for few more minutes.